# How to make the name of a file change to the Post Form's title?

Tags: python, django

In my app I want a user to upload an image and the image's file name will become same as the title of the form.

For example,
user uploads image xyz.jpg, while `title = newfile. After that the image will now be newfile.jpg.

This is my code below:

```
#forms 

class PostForm(forms.modelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = ['title', 'cover']
#urls

from django.urls import path
from .views import HomePageView, CreatePostView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('post/', CreatePostView.as_view(), name='add_post')
  ]
#views

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post

class HomePageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'

class CreatePostView(CreateView): # new
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Comment: template_name = f"{model}.html" in CreatePostView

Comment: Your code seems a bit messy. Can you fix the indentations?

Comment: fixed them hopefully that helps